# Where I can find Psychtoolbox-3.0.11?

Tags: psychtoolbox

My Matlab is 32 bit, working on my 32 bit win7 OS. I want to work with Psychtoolbox, looking for suitable version (Psychtoolbox-3.0.10/Psychtoolbox-3.0.11) that can run on my platform.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions provided by Psychtoolbox for installation:

http://psychtoolbox.org/download/

When you reach the step where you run the `DownloadPsychtoolbox` function, supply the version you would like to download via the third parameter, 'targetRevision':

http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/DownloadPsychtoolbox

So for example, to download Psychtoolbox-3.0.11, which was the last version to support 32-bit MATLAB:

```
DownloadPsychtoolbox('C:\toolbox', 'beta', 'Psychtoolbox-3.0.11')
```

Comment: I did it, and honestly, you were the motivation, or I decided to give up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. go to the Psychtoolbox archive (https://github.com/Psychtoolbox-3/Psychtoolbox-3/releases?after=PTB_Beta-2014-10-05_V3.0.12) and download  `PTB_Beta-2014-04-06_V3.0.11`
2. Unzip the folder and rename it (if you think so), move to any specific location (I prefer `C:\toolbox`)
3. Download `Slik-Subversion-1.9.7-win32` and install it (https://sliksvn.com/download/).
4. Open MATLAB (did not try Octave), change the workspace and track the folder (for me it was `cd C:\Psychtoolbox\Psychtoolbox`)
5. type `SetupPsychtoolbox`to the matlab command window (it may take a while).
6. Download any Psytoolbox Demo (http://peterscarfe.com/ptbtutorials.html) and run it normally. 
   ****** that's it, running PTB-3 in 32 bit MATLAB, in 32 bit win7 platform.